# Usage of "instead of"

Tags: grammar

Do these sentences use *instead of* properly?

> He cycles to school *instead of* drive.
>
> He cycles to school *instead of* driving.

[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instead-of) gives the example

> I wish you'd spend more time at home instead of going out drinking

which I believe licenses the second alternative above.

> He takes the bus rather than walk

seems to suggest that the first alternative is not easily judged to be unacceptable.

Comment: This would be a fair question if it were not general reference. One might expect usage of the compound preposition 'instead of' to be confined to 'N1 instead of N2' ('I had tea instead of coffee'), but [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instead-of) makes it plain that 'V ... instead of V-ing' examples such as 'I wish you'd spend more time at home instead of going out drinking' /  'He commutes to school instead of driving.' are acceptable. (Though your examples don't make sense: commuters often drive).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But to be fair to OP CDO doesn't make it plain that instead of verb-**ing** is obligatory. (It makes it plain that it's possible)

Comment: In addition to the grammatical issue, you also have an issue with meaning.  Driving is not an alternative to commuting, it's one way of commuting.  So the second choice is grammatically correct, but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Steven Littman I see you agree.

Comment: @Araucaria I'm pointing out lack of **any** reasonable research here. I've added an answer from the most relevant source I've found.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question simply, I would say that the second one is correct whilst the other is wrong. Instead of phrase should be followed by a noun or noun phrase therefore instead of+verb makes no sense and/or sounds awful. 
Also ,commute means go along the way to your business and come back. So, that could be driving, walking or even flying if you are extremely rich :) Another example could have been better.

Answer (score 0):

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instead+of) gives the following valuable analysis (bolding mine; note the 'bus' sentence):

> **instead of**
>
> **prep.**
>
> In place of; rather than: *ordered chicken instead of fish.*
>
> **conj. [??!]**
>
> Rather than.
>
> Usage Note: Traditionally, *instead of* is a preposition used like
>   *rather than*, and the two constructions
>   are often used interchangeably:
>
> *We had spaghetti instead of (or rather than) pizza.*
>
> The constructions are frequently used with participles in comparisons
>   in
>   which the alternate entity is a main verb:
>
> *Instead of (or rather than) taking the bus, we walked to the theater.*
>
> [cf *He cycles to school instead of driving.*]
>
> *Rather than* has a further use as a conjunction when the comparison is of one main verb with another: We took the bus rather than walk. In
>   these constructions, *instead of* is sometimes used as well –
>   something that, under the word's traditional categorization as a
>   preposition, would seem a grammatical error. But in our 2005 survey,
>   63 percent of the Usage Panel allowed the sentence
>
> *We would have liked to buy instead of rent, but prices were just too high.*
>
> Writers should bear in mind, however, that this use of instead of is
>   somewhat informal.

I'd go further and say that 'He cycles to school instead of drive.' is unacceptable; notice that the example above has two infinitives (one a to-infinitive), one on either side of the 'instead of'. 'He likes to cycle to school instead of drive.' is fine, at least in an informal register.

There is further discussion at [Englishrules.com/writing/2005...](https://www.englishrules.com/writing/2005/rather-than-and-instead-of/) in an article from the American Heritage Book of English Usage, with more detail on the possible pairings of the verb-forms before and after the related expression 'rather than' (which are however not identical to those acceptable with 'instead of').